# How can i put alert dialog box in loop specially in for loop Android

Tags: java, android

I want to add different dialog box for different contacts ..!! and i want create in following for loop and here is my code ..!!

```
public class CallActivity extends Activity{

    sqlAdapter adapter;
    Context mContext; 
    String Birthdate, CurrentDate, ctName = "Unknown", phNumber = "Unknown";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int date = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```

/* For geting Current Date */

```
    if(date<10 && month<10){
        CurrentDate = "0"+month+"-0"+date;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CurrentDate : " + CurrentDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(month<10 && date>10){
            CurrentDate = "0"+month+"-"+date;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CurrentDate : " + CurrentDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else if(month>9 && date<10){
            CurrentDate = month+"-0"+date;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CurrentDate : " + CurrentDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }else {
            CurrentDate = month+"-"+date;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CurrentDate : " + CurrentDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

    adapter = new sqlAdapter(getBaseContext());
    adapter.openToRead();
    ArrayList<ContactDetails> cDetails = adapter.getContactDetails(CurrentDate);
    adapter.close();
```

/* this is for loop where i want to generate alert dialog box for different contacts */

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cDetails.size(); i++) {
        ctName = cDetails.get(i).Name;
        adapter.openToRead();
        phNumber = adapter.getcNumber(ctName);
        adapter.close();
        alertforcall(getBaseContext(),ctName,phNumber);
    }   
}

public void alertforcall(Context context, String Name, final String ctNumber){
    mContext = context;

    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CallActivity.this).create();
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alert.setTitle("");
    alert.setMessage("Are you sure want to call " + Name +"? " );

    alert.setButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();

        }
    });

    alert.setButton2("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String phoneNumber = "tel:" + ctNumber;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                    .parse(phoneNumber));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();           
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: I read your question few times and didnt understand what you want. So, what do you want?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: if in array list which i mentioned above have two values than previous value is overriding with current value ... how can i show a particular dialog box for particular contact.

Answer (score 5):

**Bad Practice**, Creating a Dialog in **for-loop** is not a Good Programming practice.

Just pass, a **ArrayList of Contact** to `alertforcall()` method, and When you want to show the dialog on condition base set the Name and Contact in that **AlertDialog**..

**For example,**

Now, when you want to show alert dialog for particular contact, I assume you are clicking on Contact List, So by getting Name and Number for particular List Item and passing it to `alertforcall()` method You can show particular Alert Dialog.

Comment: No...!! for only one contact its work fine for me. but if there are more than one contact with birthday today its not working fine.

Comment: Then also it simple, Just pass a ArrayList, And on the size of ArrayList display Dialog one by one, You have to first display dialog for one contact, if dialog dismissed then check the second value for Contact list till last entry..

Comment: Just **create One Dialog and Change the Name and Numbers for Different Contacts**. It is the feasible way.

Comment: I have already done that in my for loop ..!! i m passing ArrayList, And on the size of ArrayList display Dialog one by one

Comment: You are creating new dialog for every iteration  `AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CallActivity.this).create();`